# LaTeX sometimes puts too much or too little space after periods

Tags: latex

LaTeX tries to guess whether a period ends a sentence, in which case it puts extra space after it.
Here are two examples where it guesses wrong:

```
I watched Superman III. Then I went home.
```

(Too little space after "Superman III.".)

```
After brushing teeth etc. I went to bed.
```

(Too much space after "etc.".)

Note that it doesn't matter how much whitespace you use in the LaTeX source since LaTeX ignores that.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I found the answer here:  http://john.regehr.org/latex/. Excerpt:

When a non-sentence-ending period is to be followed by a space, the space must be an explicit blank.
So the second example should be:

```
After brushing teeth etc.\ I went to bed.
```

The converse of this problem happens when a capital letter precedes a sentence-ending period in the input, as in the first example.
In this case LaTeX assumes that the period terminates an abbreviation and follows it with inter-word space rather than inter-sentence space.
The fix is to put "`\@`" before the period.
So the first example should be

```
I watched Superman III\@. Then I went home.
```

A handy way to find this error is:

```
grep '[A-Z]\.' *.tex
```

Comment: The command "\@" is in fact specifically for this purpose -- to precede a non-sentence-ending period.

Comment: And you can also write `etc.\@ I went to bed.` if you like the symmetry.

Comment: @dreeves: according to the response and my experience, `\@` is designed to precede a sentence-ending period, the opposite of what you said.

Comment: Eep, yes, it's correct in my answer but I said it backwards in my first comment above.

Comment: Also see [Good practice on spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/good-practice-on-spacing) and [Correct punctuation spaces](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/827168808/correct-punctuation-spaces) where @Will Robertson write: 'You should consider `\@.` a "sentence-ending period" and `.\@` an "abbreviation period"'.

Answer (score 15):

You can sidestep the spacing issue if you prefer single spaces at the end of sentences: put `\frenchspacing` on (for older versions of Latex this was a fragile command).  Knuth was following the traditional naming in calling it French spacing, although calling double spacing after sentences French spacing has become dominant in publishing.

Dirk Margulis wrote a nice post summarising some of the reasons for the prevalance of single spacing: [Space between sentences](http://www.techwr-l.com/archives/9907/techwhirl-9907-01344.html).

Answer (score 5):

I like the answer from dreeves and the handy search he suggests too.  I don't have the Stackoverflow "rep" points to comment, but...

Since lines in raw *.tex tend to be very long, the output from grep can be overwhelming (i.e., entire paragraphs); I suggest a variation to only display the words ending in '[A-Z].' (followed by one or more space, followed by a new capitalized word).  It is,

```
grep -o -E '[A-Z]+\. +[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]+' *.tex
```