# How to delete sentences starting with a lower case letter?

Tags: python, regex, perl, text

In the example below the following regex (".*?") was used to remove all dialogue first. 
The next step is to remove all remaining sentences starting with a lower case letter. 
Only sentences starting with an upper case letter should remain.

Example:

> exclaimed Wade. Indeed, below them were villages, of crude huts made of timber 
>   and stone and mud. Rubble work walls, for they needed little shelter here, and 
>   the people were but savages.
>
> asked Arcot, his voice a bit unsteady with suppressed excitement.
>
> replied Morey without turning from his station at the window. Below them now, 
>   less than half a mile down on the patchwork of the Nile valley, men were standing, 
>   staring up, collecting in little groups, gesticulating toward the strange thing 
>   that had materialized in the air above them.

In the example above the following should be deleted only:

> exclaimed Wade.
>   asked Arcot, his voice a bit unsteady with suppressed excitement.
>   replied Morey without turning from his station at the window.

A useful regex or simple Perl or python code is appreciated. I'm using version 7 of Textpipe.

Thanks.

Comment: Realistically there's no such thing as a regex that matches "a sentence".

Answer (score 3):

This should work for the example you posted:

```
text = re.sub(r'(^|(?<=[.!?])\s+)[a-z].*?[.!?](?=\s|$)', r'\1', text)
```

Comment: This might have trouble with a sentence that contains, say, "foo.com".

Comment: Detecting the end of sentences reliably is not easy. We do what we can, and often it's good enough (e.g. it works on the example in the question). However, I've added a requirement of space/end-of-line after the period/question mark/exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Perl on your example:

```
$s = "exclaimed Wade. Indeed, ...";

do {
  $prev = $s;
  $s =~ s/(^\s*|[.!?]\s+)[a-z][^.!?]*[.!?]\s*/$1/gs;
} until ($s eq $prev);
```

Without the do loop it had trouble with removing multiple consecutive sentences.

Note that doing this perfectly is pretty much [AI-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete).
See this question for examples of the kind of sentences that you'll never get right:
[LaTeX sometimes puts too much or too little space after periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024338/latex-sometimes).

Of course you could use LaTeX's heuristic for what's a sentence-ending period and get it right most of the time.

Comment: Ironically, this won't work with sentences containing periods.

Comment: I don't understand.  I did test it with sentences that contain strings like "abc.def" and it works.  Arguably my code does the wrong thing when a sentence contains "abc.Def".  (But maybe it depends on the corpus whether that's more likely to a be an intra-word or sentence-ending period.) Or do you mean sentences with periods like "I love E.B. White."?  That's a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a module like [Lingua::EN::Sentence](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua::EN::Sentence)?  It makes it very easy  to get pretty good sentences from arbitrary English text.

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Lingua::EN::Sentence qw( get_sentences );

my $text = <<END;

exclaimed Wade. Indeed, below them were villages, of crude huts made of timber and stone and mud. Rubble work walls, for they needed little shelter here, and the people were but savages.

asked Arcot, his voice a bit unsteady with suppressed excitement.

replied Morey without turning from his station at the window. Below them now, less than half a mile down on the patchwork of the Nile valley, men were standing, staring up, collecting in little groups, gesticulating toward the strange thing that had materialized in the air above them.
END


my $sentences = matching_sentences( qr/^[^a-z]/, $text );

print map "$_\n", @$sentences;

sub matching_sentences {
    my $re   = shift;
    my $text = shift;

    my $s = get_sentences( $text );

    @$s = grep /$re/, @$s;

    return $s;
}
```

Results:

```
Indeed, below them were villages, of crude huts made of timber and stone and mud.
Rubble work walls, for they needed little shelter here, and the people were but savages.
Below them now, less than half a mile down on the patchwork of the Nile valley, men were standing, staring up, collecting in little groups, gesticulating toward the strange thing that had materialized in the air above them.
```